# btrfs send / receive on incremental folders that rotate

Tags: backup, clone, mirror, btrfs, rsnapshot

I am using incremental backups using `rsnapshot` combined with a custom
`cmd_cp` and `cmd_rm` to make use of btrfs snapshots, this procudes multiple
daily btrfs subvolumes:

```
.sync
daily.0
daily.1
daily.2
```

`.sync` is the folder that gets synced to using SSH from the server I backup.
When completed this happens:

```
mv daily.2/ daily.3/
mv daily.1/ daily.2/
mv daily.0/ daily.1/
rsnapshot_cp_btrfs -al .sync daily.0
```

The cp command translates into `btrfs subvolume snapshot -r .sync daily.0`.

This all works great. But now I want to sync all backups to an other server
too, so I have a full mirror of all backups. This sync should always work,
even if it would be synced a week after (maybe due SSH connection issues).

Normally syncing would be easy using btrfs send and receive using parent
snapshots as described on the wiki:
https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup#Doing_it_by_hand.2C_step_by_step

I imagined a loop that just sends all daily folders and maintaining the old
backup for parent reference.

But in this case `daily.0` moves to `daily.1`, 1 to 2, and so on. So this would not work.

I could send a simple `mv` to the remote server, but I can't trust this since
on any errors, the folder structures would not be proper a day later. I want a true mirror, but making use of the btrfs tools.

Did anyone managed a similar situation or know the best way to clone all
subvolumes to the other server?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it! I created a bash script that syncs all snapshots with a date in the name  to the remote server. The date is subtracted from `btrfs subvolume show`.

So `daily.0` can become `2021-09-20-08-44-46` on the remote.

I sync backwards. `daily.30` first. `daily.0` last. This way I can pass the
proper parent to `btrfs send`. E.g.: `btrfs send -p daily.30 daily.29`.

If the date named snapshot exists on the remote, I check with `btrfs subvolume show`
whether it was properly synced. If not, I delete the remote subvolume/snapshot and
re-sync. If it was already synced, I will skip the sync. A proper synced subvolume/snapshot has a `Received UUID` and `readonly` flag.

After syncing I compare all snapshot names of the remote to what was just synced.
The difference will deleted (thus old snapshots).

I might share the code in the future when it's all been stable for a long run.
For now I hope the above information will help others!